# Simplification of a volume integral

Tags: integration, divergence-theorem, finite-volume-method

While trying to simplify an equation in the integral form (in the context of finite volume method with polyhedral meshes), I came across this term:

$$
\iiint_V{\vec v\nabla\cdot\vec c\,\mathrm dV} \label{1}\tag{1}
$$
where $\vec v$ and $\vec c$ are two vector fields.
In the other hand, I have the following relation that holds for every control volume $V$ that is fixed (not changing over time):
$$
\iiint_V{\nabla\cdot \vec c}\,\mathrm dV \equiv 0 \label{2}\tag{2}
$$

**My question**: is it possible to simplify the expression \eqref{1}?
Here is what I am doing:

- From \eqref{2}, we can get: $\nabla\cdot \vec c=0$ because the volume is arbitrary.
- Substituting that in (1), yields:

$$
\iiint_V{\vec v\nabla\cdot\vec c\,\mathrm dV} = \iiint_V{\vec v \cdot 0\,\mathrm dV} = 0
$$

Is that correct?
I appreciate your help

Comment: Your last equation doesn't make sense because the LHS is a vector and the RHS is a scalar.

Comment: @Paul, in the last equation both integands are vectors: divergence of $\vec c$ is a scalar multiplied by the vector $\vec v$

Comment: @Winther: Yes, that holds for every cell with Volume $V$

Comment: It seems correct.

Comment: You intuition is correct: from \eqref{2} you can infer that $\nabla\cdot\vec{c}=0$ almost everywhere on the volume $\Omega$ to which all your control volumes $V$ belong, thus you can simplify \eqref{1} as you did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If (2) holds for any volume element then $\nabla \cdot \vec{c}$ is identically zero and your claim is true. This is a standard behavior in transport equations (like Navier Stokes). However, you typically also have a term like  $(\vec{v} \cdot \nabla) \vec{c}$ (coming from moving along the flow)  which is non-trivial in this context.